# Transparency issue - when converting UIView to UIImage

Tags: ios, uiview, uiimage, transparency

I want to create an `UIImage` object from a `UIView`. The view is NOT opaque.
for that i'm using the following code:

```
+ (UIImage *) imageWithView:(UIView *)view 
{     
    UIGraphicsBeginImageContextWithOptions(view.bounds.size, view.opaque, [[UIScreen mainScreen] scale]);     
    [view.layer renderInContext:UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext()];     
    UIImage * img = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext();  
    UIGraphicsEndImageContext();     
    return img; 
}
```

But for some reason instead of transparent background i'm getting a image with black background.
I already tried to set the "opaque" parameter in `UIGraphicsBeginImageContextWithOptions` to `NO` but with no different results.

Any suggestion?

(Similar question [CGContext transparency problem](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4525127/cgcontext-transparency-problem) with no answer)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm pretty sure you can't define a transparency when creating UIImages like this - you could mask your UIImageView which uses the image though.

Something like the following functions allow for this type of operation:

```
// handles img masking operation
CGImageRef CopyImageAndAddAlphaChannel(CGImageRef sourceImage) {
    CGImageRef retVal = NULL;

    size_t width = CGImageGetWidth(sourceImage);
    size_t height = CGImageGetHeight(sourceImage);

    CGColorSpaceRef colorSpace = CGColorSpaceCreateDeviceRGB();

    CGContextRef offscreenContext = CGBitmapContextCreate(NULL, width, height, 
                                                          8, 0, colorSpace, kCGImageAlphaPremultipliedFirst);

    if (offscreenContext != NULL) {
        CGContextDrawImage(offscreenContext, CGRectMake(0, 0, width, height), sourceImage);

        retVal = CGBitmapContextCreateImage(offscreenContext);
        CGContextRelease(offscreenContext);
    }

    CGColorSpaceRelease(colorSpace);

    return retVal;
}
    // png masks can mask png, gif or jpg...
- (UIImage*)maskImage:(UIImage *)image withMask:(UIImage *)maskImage 
{
    CGImageRef maskRef = maskImage.CGImage;
    CGImageRef mask = CGImageMaskCreate(CGImageGetWidth(maskRef),
                                        CGImageGetHeight(maskRef),
                                        CGImageGetBitsPerComponent(maskRef),
                                        CGImageGetBitsPerPixel(maskRef),
                                        CGImageGetBytesPerRow(maskRef),
                                        CGImageGetDataProvider(maskRef), NULL, false);

    CGImageRef sourceImage = [image CGImage];
    CGImageRef imageWithAlpha = sourceImage;
    //add alpha channel for images that don't have one (ie GIF, JPEG, etc...)
    //this however has a computational cost
    if ((CGImageGetAlphaInfo(sourceImage) == kCGImageAlphaNone) || (CGImageGetAlphaInfo(sourceImage) == kCGImageAlphaNoneSkipFirst)) 
    { 
        imageWithAlpha = CopyImageAndAddAlphaChannel(sourceImage);
    }

    CGImageRef masked = CGImageCreateWithMask(imageWithAlpha, mask);
    CGImageRelease(mask);

    //release imageWithAlpha if it was created by CopyImageAndAddAlphaChannel
    if (sourceImage != imageWithAlpha) 
    {
        CGImageRelease(imageWithAlpha);
    }

    UIImage* retImage = [UIImage imageWithCGImage:masked];
    CGImageRelease(masked);

    return retImage;
}
```

You can than call it like this:

```
UIImage *imgMasked = [self maskImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"full_image.png"] withMask:[UIImage imageNamed:@"masked_image.png"]];
```

masked_image.png needs to be an alpha channeled image which will cut out your black bg.

Comment: Can you please give me more detail what do you mean by "masking my image view"? And will it accomplish what i'm trying to achive?

Comment: can gif image be used as masking image?

Comment: @Lemonsanver: CopyImageAndAddAlphaChannel I got this as undefined symbol.. Please tell me what can do now

Answer (score 46):

Unless I'm missing something, I believe you get the result you want by setting opaque to NO

```
UIGraphicsBeginImageContextWithOptions( CGSize size, BOOL opaque, CGFloat scale );


+ (UIImage *) imageWithView:(UIView *)view 
{     
    UIGraphicsBeginImageContextWithOptions(view.bounds.size, NO, [[UIScreen mainScreen] scale]);     
    [view.layer renderInContext:UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext()];     
    UIImage * img = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext();     UIGraphicsEndImageContext();     
    return img; 
}
```

Comment: hahaha great answer. not sure why this isn't marked as the solution but w.e!

Comment: Instead of explicitly setting opaque parameter to NO, use 'view.opaque' instead, provided that the view has been defined as not opaque.  This allows the same code to work for opaque and non-opaque views.

Comment: This worked! Thanks so much. Can't some moderator set this as the correct answer?

Comment: Dude, you are a reminder for all of us, that we need to actually read functions' signatures and descriptions to them...

Answer (score 0):

i just came across this same problem. what worked for me was assuring that i was working with PNGs and not JPGs, since JPGs do not support alpha channel. hope this works for you.