# Take a screenshot of a UIPickerView

Tags: ios, objective-c

I use the following code to take a screenshot of my view:

```
UIGraphicsBeginImageContextWithOptions(containerView.bounds.size, NO, [[UIScreen mainScreen] scale]);
[toController.view.layer renderInContext:UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext()];
UIImage *image = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext();
UIGraphicsEndImageContext();
```

It works perfectly for most cases, but produces the below image when a view contains a `UIPickerView`

[image: image that is produced]

And this is the image that I would like to produce.

[image: the desired image]

What's going on and how can I solve this, any ideas??

Thanks all!

EDIT: Just to note this occurs on both the device and the simulator

Comment: Try creating a snapshot of `UIPickerView` with `snapshotViewAfterScreenUpdates:` and render the returned `UIView` as an image. Also, take a look at [THIS POST](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4933338/problem-with-transparency-when-converting-uiview-to-uiimage).

Comment: @n00bProgrammer great stuff, it works when using `drawViewHierarchyInRect: afterScreenUpdates:` thanks for helping me get there

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I solved the problem by using `drawViewHierarchyInRect:`

```
UIGraphicsBeginImageContextWithOptions(containerView.bounds.size, NO, [[UIScreen mainScreen] scale]);
[toController.view drawViewHierarchyInRect:containerView.bounds afterScreenUpdates:YES];
UIImage * image = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext();
UIGraphicsEndImageContext();
```